# Ionic 4 App 192.168.8.200 not working on mobile device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Im tried to serve  **ionic 4 mobile app** on using mobile browser, but its not worked for me. **http://localhost:8100** is really worked on local server, **Ionic 3** app is relay working following method  **192.168.8.200:8100**
anyone know how run the ionic 4 app different devices using **IP address**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. learn what IP address your machine has (windows, run "ipconfig")
2. run 'ionic serve --address 192.168.0.72' (my address is 192.168.0.72 on dev PC)
3. now from another device on local network go: 192.168.0.72:8100

You can change port as well as needed:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/serve

**Please note** with this command you will also need to use this IP address to debug instead of localhost:8100. Your browser by default will still try to get to localhost first.

**Update 2:**

Try also running it this way: 'ionic serve --address 0.0.0.0'

This way both localhost and 192.168.0.72 (my PC interface) work.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Please use the --host option (e.g. --host=192.168.0.24) to specify the host of the dev server.

example: *ionic serve --address 0.0.0.0*

Answer (score 2):

For Ionic using Angular:
ng run app:serve --host=192.168.8.200 --port=8100